# What is 心を無にする supposed to mean?

Tags: meaning

I was reading Abe Shinzo's twitter for some explainable reason, and I found a tweet where he says 心を無にする. It feels wonderfully *Japanese* to me given the fact that it involves heart and doing nothing, and while I can read it, I have no idea what exactly its actually trying to say, thus I ask... what does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

心を無にする means 雑念をを取り払う. 雑念 means distraction. A dictionary says it means "free one's mind from worldly thoughts", "shut out idle thoughts from one's mind". And it implies "to focus something by eliminating distraction".

Leaders must decide many important things and receive lots of information from others every day. There would be sometimes when they are confused with too much information. At such time, the phrase would be used.

This may be helpful.[http://潜在意識なび.net/%E7%B2%BE%E7%A5%9E/%E5%BF%83%E3%82%92%E7%84%A1%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/](http://%E6%BD%9C%E5%9C%A8%E6%84%8F%E8%AD%98%E3%81%AA%E3%81%B3.net/%E7%B2%BE%E7%A5%9E/%E5%BF%83%E3%82%92%E7%84%A1%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95/)